# display icon in a column in react-table on mouseover/enter

Tags: reactjs, react-table

Using [React-table](https://react-table.tanstack.com/). Want to show/hide an icon in a single column on mouse enter/exit. Changing the row background via css is nbd but haven't found the trick to altering css for a single cell on row mouseover.

Wanted to know if there was a straightforward method before I start spinning a web-of-states to push the signal around.

Answer (score 0):

FWIW:

1. in the column descriptor:

```
Cell: ({row}) =>  <div className={`${rootClass}__table-icon`} row-key={row.id}}><SVGItem/></div>
```

2. make sure the <tr> has `onMouseEnter` and `onMouseLeave` defined
3. add:

```
function rowMouseEnter(row:any) {
    document.querySelector("[row-key='" + row.id + "']").className = `${rootClass}__table-icon-selected`
}

function rowMouseLeave(row:any) {
    document.querySelector("[row-key='" + row.id + "']").className = `${rootClass}__table-icon`
}
```

4. in css add

`&__table-icon-selected: visibility: visible`

and

`&__table-icon: visibility: none`